# SQL query - tracking which rows in an interrupted sequence are related to eachother

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

I have a table consisting of actions that are logged when users are viewing files. When a user views a file, this can result in multiple actions over time. As multiple users can be active at the same time, their actions can become intertwined.

I am looking to create an additional column in my query that tells me when a user started viewing this file (let's call this StartId).

When a user stops viewing a file to view some other file, and then goes back to viewing the first file, this should be regarded as a new viewing session.

This table illustrates my problem and my desired result:

| Id | User | File | StartId (desired result) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | X | 1 |
| 2 | A | X | 1 |
| 3 | B | Y | 3 |
| 4 | A | X | 1 |
| 5 | B | Y | 3 |
| 6 | A | Y | 6 |
| 7 | A | X | 7 |

The closest I have come is with this line:

`StartId = FIRST_VALUE(Id) OVER (PARTITION BY User, File ORDER BY Id)`

However, this has the following result for the last action in the example:

| Id | User | File | StartId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | A | X | 1 |

Can someone point me in the right direction with this?

Comment: Can you please tag the database / sql dialect to be used, valid solutions which use lag / lead for example may not work for you because of the database being used.

Comment: I am not sure how you could get that result (this is likely postgreSQL, is it?). And if you only need the User, File, FirstId then I don't think you need a windowing function but simply a group by for this.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I've added the tag, I'm using SQL Server 2016

Comment: @CetinBasoz I don't think a group by would solve my problem because I want to keep each individual row, even though multiple rows can be part of the same 'viewing session'

Comment: OK that is fine. Then we need to find out how you could get that result. You are not using identifiers on keywords and this may not be your real field names. It works right in fact: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0260ba8ae23da66b2a39cb689dd55780

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you are asking, the part you say "However...." is what it should return.

Comment: @CetinBasoz - your db fiddle assigns Row 7 a StartId of 1. They don't want that because the user "A" went from file x to file y and then back to file x. So they should get a new session when they return

Comment: @MartinSmith, I see what you are saying. Doesn't make any sense to me. A user could open and work on multiple files at a time (happens to me often).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `LAG` to see if the previous file for the same user was the same as the current file for that user and so whether we are in a new session or not and then use that result accordingly.

```
WITH T AS
(
SELECT *, 
       CASE WHEN "File" = LAG("File") OVER (PARTITION BY "User" ORDER BY "Id") THEN NULL ELSE "Id" END AS NewSessionFlag
FROM  YourTable
)
SELECT *, 
       MAX(NewSessionFlag) OVER (PARTITION BY "User" ORDER BY "Id" ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
FROM T
ORDER BY "Id"
```

[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=28254eaec54de06904f0cb488f038032)

Comment: Thank you so much! I wasn't familiar with the LAG function yet, I will definitely remember it from now on :)